# mysql procedure syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, procedure

I get an error by sending the following query (MYSQL 5.0):

```sql
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE relationTable ()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE articlecount int;
        DECLARE keywordcount int;
        DECLARE articlehits int;
        DECLARE ac int DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE kc int;
        DECLARE articleid int;
        DECLARE word varchar(100);
        DECLARE word_id int;
        SET articlehits = 0;
        SET articlecount = (SELECT count(id) from articles);
        SET keywordcount = (SELECT count(id) from keywords);
        outerloop: WHILE (ac < articlecount) DO
            SET kc = 0;
            SET articleid = (SELECT id from articles LIMIT 1 OFFSET ac);
            innerloop: WHILE (kc < keywordcount) DO
                IF (articlehits < 5) THEN
                    SELECT keyword, id INTO word, word_id from keywords LIMIT 1 OFFSET kc;
                    IF (0 < (SELECT COUNT(id) from articles WHERE id=articleid AND CONCAT(title, " ",text) REGEXP word)) THEN
                        INSERT INTO articles (id, articleID, keywordID, type) VALUES(NULL, articleid, word_id, 'type1');
                        SET articlehits = articlehits + 1;
                    END IF;
                    SET kc = kc + 1;
                ELSE
                    SET kc = keywordcount;
                END IF;
            END WHILE innerloop;
            SET ac = ac + 1;
        END WHILE outerloop;
    END;
    //
    DELIMITER ;
```

This produces the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1 OFFSET ac); innerloop: WHILE (kc <
>   keywordcount) DO TO word, word_id from' at line 15

Any idea why this happens?

(Wrote this to create a relation table between articles and keywords, to enable smart-links in article view.)

Comment: 1.  Is the strange skip in the error report from the word DO and the word fragment TO part of your question?

Comment: 2.  Is it possible that you need to SELECT INTO user-defined variables instead of declared procedure variables?

Comment: What do you mean by "user-defined" variables?

Comment: and yes I'm also wondering about the fragmentation of this error output

Comment: MySQL has connection-specific user-defined variables of the form @varname and declared procedure variables of the type you are using.  In my experience with procedures, sometimes only one of the types is allowed, and if I recall correctly, one of those situations may be when SELECTing INTO.  I'll make this into an answer in case you want to mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the while labels:

```
WHILE (ac < articlecount) DO
            SET kc = 0;
            SET articleid = (SELECT id from articles LIMIT 1 OFFSET ac);
            WHILE (kc < keywordcount) DO
                IF (articlehits < 5) THEN
                    SELECT keyword, id INTO word, word_id from keywords LIMIT 1 OFFSET kc;
                    IF (0 < (SELECT COUNT(id) from articles WHERE id=articleid AND CONCAT(title, " ",text) REGEXP word)) THEN
                        INSERT INTO articles (id, articleID, keywordID, type) VALUES(NULL, articleid, word_id, 'type1');
                        SET articlehits = articlehits + 1;
                    END IF;
                    SET kc = kc + 1;
                ELSE
                    SET kc = keywordcount;
                END IF;
            END WHILE;
            SET ac = ac + 1;
        END WHILE;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has connection-specific user-defined variables of the form @varname and declared procedure variables of the type you are using in your code sample.  In my experience with procedures, sometimes only one of the types is allowed, and if I recall correctly, one of those situations may be when SELECTing INTO.  You might try using user-defined variables here, as follows:

```
    SET articleid = (SELECT id from articles LIMIT 1 OFFSET ac);
    innerloop: WHILE (kc < keywordcount) DO
        IF (articlehits < 5) THEN
            SELECT keyword, id INTO @word, @word_id from keywords LIMIT 1 OFFSET kc;
```

Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

One problem may be the SET acticleid = (SELECT...). Try with `SELECT .. INTO`:

```
SELECT id INTO @articleid FROM articles LIMIT 1 OFFSET ac;
```

Variable `LIMIT` in stored procedures is only supported in new MySQL versions. Note that since you dont have an `ORDER BY` you will get a random row. It looks like you want to use a `CURSOR` instead. See [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cursors.html).

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of seeming over-critical, I believe you should rewrite this procedure to use cursors for traversing your databases, instead of individual selects with LIMIT.

see [Cursors in MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cursors.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your help so far.
The idea of Tom Haws proved to be correct. The variables for a SELECT INTO statement have to be user-defined.
I edited my code to use cursors, and user-defined variables as followed:

```sql
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE relationTable ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE articlehits int;
    DECLARE looparticles int DEFAULT TRUE;
    DECLARE loopwords int DEFAULT TRUE;
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;     
    DECLARE keywordcursor CURSOR FOR SELECT keyword, id FROM keywords;
    DECLARE articlecursor CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM articles;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE; 
    OPEN articlecursor;
    WHILE (looparticles) DO
        FETCH articlecursor INTO @articleid;
        IF done THEN SET looparticles = FALSE;
        ELSE
            SET articlehits = 0;
            OPEN keywordcursor;
            WHILE (loopwords) DO
                FETCH keywordcursor INTO @word, @wordid;
                IF (articlehits < 5) AND NOT done THEN
                    IF (0 < (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM articles WHERE id=@articleid AND CONCAT(title, " ", text) REGEXP @word)) THEN
                        INSERT INTO keyword_article_rel (id, meldungID, wordID) VALUES(NULL, @articleid, @wordid);
                        SET articlehits = articlehits + 1;
                    END IF;
                ELSE
                    SET loopwords = FALSE;
                    CLOSE keywordcursor;
                    SET done = FALSE;
                END IF;
            END WHILE;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
    CLOSE articlecursor;
    END;
    //
    delimiter ;
```

And now I get an other error that I really can't explain:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '; DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
>   OPEN articlecursor; W' at line 6

This error confuses me because it can't have a problem with the handler. The handler is declared as in the [example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html) of the mysql-documentation. Could the problem be that I can't create **two** cursors like this?